# Text inline with image rising to top of image, padding top won't work?

Tags: html, css

Alright so for the header of my site I've a small logo image, then I need two links spaced out through the header.

With two links in, it works to space them, but they're way up at the top and I can't figure out how to lower them?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="header">
    <img src="assets/caliweb.png" alt="CALi Logo"> 
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Patents Pending</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Partner with Us</a></p>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.header p {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;

}

.header img{
    float: left;
    padding-top: 
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    display: inline;


}
```

This is what I tried, that's not working at all, the links are below the image.

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
      <div class="headerlogo">
        <img src="assets/caliweb.png" alt="CALi Logo"> 
          </div>
          <div class="headertext">
          <p><a href="#">Patents Pending</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Partner with Us</a></p>
      </div>  
    </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
display:inline;
}

.headertext {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;

}

.headerlogo{
    float: left;
    padding-top: 
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    display: inline;


}
```

I keep making ignorant/naive mistakes, but y'all have been incredibly helpful at helping me fix them. I greatly appreciate it.

EDIT
I found my most recent problem. Whilst retyping the code, I left a  and accidentally closed the text out of the .header tag. It's all good now, thank you.

Comment: One thing - In your, .header img along with your .headerlogo, you have padding-top: without a value.

Comment: Touche. I'll take that out, that's probably a mess  up from rewriting the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your .headertext {display:block;} ... or inline-block

**Inline elements and padding**

While padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content.

**Inline elements and margins**

While the left and right edges are effected, the content above and below are not.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick with your html structure, use display: inline-block instead of display: inline.

I would rather wrap links with "nav" and "ul" tags. Then float .header, nav and li's to the left and add margin-top to nav.

Comment: Well it had worked, but now that I went through and did it to all my pages it didn't work suddenly. So keep the image wrapped in .header div tag but wrap the links in nav & ul tags?